# Special hover effect with SCSS without code redundancy

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like to display boxes with special effects in a diagram.

- The boxes should have a color based on their category (blue, orange, etc).
- If the category is not defined, they should have a default color (e.g. white).
- "Expandable" boxes should be displayed in a predefined color (e.g. green).
- When the mouse pointer is over an expandable box, they should be displayed in their original color (based on the category). This is the tricky part.
- No JavaScript should be used.

I have a working solution, but I have at least two concerns with it.

- Primary problem is that the original colors need to be explicitly/redundantly defined in the :hover selectors.
- Secondary problem is that the order of the CSS selectors cannot be changed freely, because it will change the behavior.

main.scss contents:

```scss
$nodeDefaultColor: white;
$nodeCategory1Color: blue;
$nodeCategory2Color: orange;
$nodeExpandColor: green;

.container {
    display:flex;
}

.container > div {
    margin: 10px;
}

.node {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: $nodeDefaultColor;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.nodeCategory1 {
    background-color: $nodeCategory1Color;
}

.nodeCategory2 {
    background-color: $nodeCategory2Color;
}

.nodeExpandable {
    background-color: $nodeExpandColor;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.node.nodeExpandable:hover {
    background-color: $nodeDefaultColor;
}

.nodeCategory1.nodeExpandable:hover {
    background-color: $nodeCategory1Color;
}

.nodeCategory2.nodeExpandable:hover {
    background-color: $nodeCategory2Color;
}
```

index.html contents:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="node nodeCategory1"></div>
<div class="node nodeCategory2"></div>
<div class="node"></div>
<div class="node nodeCategory1 nodeExpandable"></div>
<div class="node nodeCategory2 nodeExpandable"></div>
<div class="node nodeExpandable"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want to Do this with SCSS Right?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's Help You

```
$nodeDefaultColor: white;
$nodeCategory1Color: blue;
$nodeCategory2Color: orange;
$nodeExpandColor: green;

.container {
    display:flex;
    > div {
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .node {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-color: black;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: $nodeDefaultColor;
        cursor: pointer;
        &.nodeCategory1 {
            background-color: $nodeCategory1Color;
            &.nodeExpandable {
                &:hover {
                    background-color: $nodeCategory1Color;
                }
            }
        }
        &.nodeCategory2 {
            background-color: $nodeCategory2Color;
            &.nodeExpandable {
                &:hover {
                    background-color: $nodeCategory2Color;
                }
            }
        }
        &.nodeExpandable {
            background-color: $nodeExpandColor;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        &:hover {
            background-color: $nodeDefaultColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It has incorrect UI behavior. Non-expandable nodes should not have any kind of hover effect